# Static site with express using a public fonder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I think this is probably just a misunderstanding of how to do this on my part but its bugging me and I haven't found anything to answer the problem.

I have a static site where my file structure is

```
--node_modules
--index.html
--server.js
--app.js
```

my server.js is simple its just

```
var express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/question', function(req, res){
    res.send(req.body);
});

// Start the server on port 3000
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Print out a nice message so you know that the server started
console.log('Server running on port 3000');
```

and my bootstrap and angular WORKS...your probably wondering what the problem is....

So I have a 2nd site and I building and thought I would organize my stuff a little better.  My file structure is

```
--node_modules
--public
|---index.html
|---app.js
--server.js
```

The only difference in my server.js is

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

my bootstrap and angular is referenced in index.html like

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This DOESN'T work!...now I know I could just do it the first way or use a CND but I was wondering if anyone could educate me as to why and what I am doing wrong.

All help and education is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don´t you mean folder (not fonder) and CDN (not CND)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular and Bootstrap probably shouldn't be in `node_modules` unless you are using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).  Express won't serve any static files that aren't under the `express.static` root, so you can't use `../` relative paths if they go higher than `public/`.

That is, you need to move everything that you want to be public somewhere under `public/` including `index.html` and the JavaScript libraries you will use.

Comment: I knew it was simple lol...so what is the best practices for including angular.js...do I just dump it into public/js?

Comment: @user3271518 there are a ton of different possible solutions.  Some people like bower, you could also put it in its own folder for third party libraries